# Can you write an h5 file from an h5py object?

Tags: python, hdfs, h5py

The documentation on h5py is very good https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/quick.html though I cannot see an example or way of achieving what I need to do..

I want to read an h5 file in, adjust it in some way and write the new file to a separate location without changing the original. Is this possible? The following option doesn't suit my use case as the files are in a workflow:

```
f = h5py.File('myfile.hdf5','r+')
```

Ideally I would do something like:

```
f = h5py.File('myfile.hdf5','r')
```

... do something to f

```
f.write('newfile.hdf5')
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: There isn't a `f.write` method, is there?  What kind of thing(s) are you doing to `f`.  In other words, are just reading data from `f`?  Or modifying it and saving it back?  If you have made changes to `f`, then what's the point to making a `newfile`?

Comment: Why not copy `myfile.hdf5` to `newfile.hdf5`, then make the desired changes to `newfile.hdf5`?

Comment: Thanks kcw78, I think that suggestion makes a lot of sense for my use case.